# Dynamic listview listeners (OnItemClickListener)

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I want to make OnItemClickListener to a dynamic listview. The listview shouldn't have a fixed size. Instead it's the size of the rows in a database. But how do I create the listener concidering I can't use the current method I have since I don't know the size of the listview.

THE PROBLEM IS IN THE INNER CLASS if(position==0) { ... }

```
public class VisaUtgiftFragment extends Fragment {
    private MainActivity ui;
    private TextView tvDatabase;
    private MyDBHandler dbHandler;
    private ListView lvUtgift;



    public VisaUtgiftFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void setActivity(MainActivity ui){
        this.ui = ui;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_visa_utgift, container, false);
        tvDatabase = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvDatabaseTest);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity(), null, null, 1);
        tvDatabase.setText(dbHandler.databaseToString());
        lvUtgift = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvUtgift);
//        lvUtgift.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, [the rows in the database]));
        lvUtgift.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                dbHandler.getAllItemsInCursor(),
                new String[]{"_titel"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0));
        lvUtgift.setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewClicked());

        return view;
    }

    private class ListViewClicked implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position==0) { //Should be the clicked listview and execute the code
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) lvUtgift.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_titel"));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ui.dVisaInkomst();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is problem ?

Comment: The problem is following: I'm trying to create a handler that doesn't use the function if(position == 0){} else if(position == 1){} since I won't be able to do so many statements because the listview is dynamic and will get bigger all the time.

Comment: If i understand, you need to perform different actions based on the position clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Remove if condition from `onClickItem`.

```
private class ListViewClicked implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             Cursor cursor = (Cursor)lvUtgift.getItemAtPosition(position);
             if(cursor != null){
                 String string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_titel"));
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 ui.dVisaInkomst();
             }               
        }
    }
```

Comment: This won't help the problem. I need a way to be able to make more if statements. Example if (first listview element clicked){ ... } else if(304th listview element clicked){...}

Comment: that's not possible. Why do you need such kind of if.. else.. ?